# Is it a bad idea to take EDI onto the Geth Cruiser?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Minor Spoilers:

> So I was thinking about taking EDI onto the Geth Cruiser in Priority: Geth Dreadnaught.

Is this a terrible idea? Could she get taken over by the Geth or otherwise subverted?

Comment: Personally I think the title should be made searchable.

Comment: note her Overload comes in handy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is totally fine. I took her with me and she experienced no negative effects from being in close proximity to the Geth.

Comment: Some experience here

Comment: Based on this advice I did and had no trouble, though on the next mission (disabling the server of the fighters, don't remember the name) EDI did have some difficulties, though it was (as far as I could tell) solely story difficulties.

Comment: I did the same thing and as far as I could tell, the difficulties were only for the story like you said

Answer (score 2):

EDI's squadmate body is remote controlled. If that body is gone, she doesn't die. She can only get killed (nonfunctional) if her quantum "blue box" on the Normandy is destroyed.

That said, she had some story difficulties, but no matter what happens, you can't lose her loyalty.

Answer (score 0):

You only really have to worry about leaving someone on the ship that you probably should have taken.  Don't want to take a tech expert on your mission? [Your loss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cMfUt3c5qw).  Don't have someone with pull when you know you're going to face Cerberus? Good luck with the Guardians.  Expect lots of enemies with shields?  Better bring along someone with overload.  Worried EDI will be hacked by a bunch of geth?  You don't have to be.  The environment and enemies essentially treat any squad mate the same and don't really have any special attacks against one particular class.